# Review migration data missing on grid

Tags: magento2, review

I'm migrating prestashop review data into magento review data.

My script worked fine, meaning, I can see the review in my database.

> review

```
1,2016-02-16 16:57:45,1,42,1
2,2016-02-25 13:49:09,1,34,1
3,2016-02-25 22:49:50,1,42,1
```

Here you can see I have 2 review on the product 42

> review_detail

```
1,1,1,conquise ,"...",Tiffany xxx,94
2,1,2,conquise ,"...",Tiffany xxx,94
3,2,1,Parfait!,"...",Marjorie yyy,389
4,2,2,Parfait!,"...",Marjorie yyy,389
5,3,1,Très contente!,"...",Kevin zzz,558
6,3,2,Très contente!,"...",Kevin zzz,558
```

So there you can see I have 4 actual review (id 1 - 2 - 5 - 6) on the product 42 (2 but duplicated by store)

But now my issue is that these reviews doensn't show up in grid neither in review list neither in the product page.

Any idea where I could miss some data in the database ?

From product page it says there is 4 record, but none are found in the grid:

[image: product page review]

From Marketing menu : it just don't find anything

[image: marketing review]

Comment: did you ran `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` ?

Comment: @Pawan Yes I did but as I said it's coming from an external script ; so there might be some data missing in the database.